# Node-SASS source maps not working with React-JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to use SASS with REACT

Dummy GITHUB : https://github.com/bansalvks/react-poc-collection/tree/master/scss-with-react

The problem I am facing is that the source maps are not working.

I am using [node-sass-chokidar](https://github.com/michaelwayman/node-sass-chokidar) and using the following script to run the utility
`node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules/ ./src -o ./src --output-style=expanded  --source-map=true --source-map-root=true --watch`

As you can see in the screen shot below the file is not appearing

[image]

Comment: it's the same with react-create-app so I don't think you're doing something wrong in your setup btw

Comment: Unable to figure you why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This work with **create-react-app** but you can try in your react setup

Try this:

From "Dummy" Github webpage I found this:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5707

> The following did work for me:
>
> ```
> 1.) open node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
> 2.) replace "isEnvProduction" with "isEnvDevelopment" for the css-loader, css-module loader, sass loader and sass module loader
> (between lines 443 - 500)
> 3.) start development process with "npm start"
> ```

So simply, navigate to **node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js**

Between lines 443-500 search for:

- css-loader
- css-module
- loader
- sass-loader
- sass-module-loader

and replace **isEnvProduction** to **isEnvDevelopment**

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11925409/50423483-4b986900-0856-11e9-80bb-7f7f331e17fd.png

I have tried that and source maps now are working in chrome developer tools